# What is the equivalent this expression " => " in IE? in IE its not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

```
var myList = data.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

This expression "=>" is not workingin IE. Can anyone please tell the alternative for this expression

Comment: there is none - use a transpiler to get it right

Comment: Fallback to normal functions. `data.filter(function(v, i, a) { return a.indexOf(v) === i; });`

Comment: `data.filter(function(v,i,a){ return a.indexOf(v)===i })`. `=>` is a ES6 syntax that binds current context to callback. Since you are not using `this`, you can fallback to passing callback itself

Comment: @JaromandaX — If there is none, then a transpiler wouldn't be able to transpile it.

Comment: @Quentin - I wont argue semantics. Of course there's an alternative, and in this case it's very simple. I would think anyone using arrow functions would already know about javascript functions and how they differ